# Switching on queries to run in a view

Tags: sql-server

I have a huge view with many queries concatenated using `UNION ALL` with the first column of every query being constant.

e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW M AS (
    SELECT 'A' ID, Value FROM A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B' ID, Value FROM B
    ...
)
```

The queries are more complex in reality but the purpose here is just to switch on what queries to run like this:

```
SELECT * FROM M WHERE ID = 'A'
```

The execution plan is showing that the queries that doesn't match on `ID` never run.

I thought this was a really nice (feature?) that I could use to combine querying different but similar things through the same view.

However, I'm ending up with an even better execution plans if querying against a CTE like this:

```
WITH M AS (
    SELECT 'A' ID, Value FROM A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B' ID, Value FROM B
    ...
)
SELECT * FROM M WHERE ID = 'A'
```

Here's a partial sample of the actual query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(4), 'T   ') EntityTypeID, SystemID, TaskId EntityID 
FROM [dbo].[Task]

UNION ALL

SELECT CONVERT(char(4), 'T   ') EntityTypeID, s.SystemID, [dbo].[Task].TaskId EntityID
FROM [dbo].[Task] 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[System] s ON s.MasterSystemID = [dbo].[Task].SystemID
INNER JOIN SystemEntitySettings ON SystemEntitySettings.SystemID = s.SystemID
    AND SystemEntitySettings.EntityTypeID = 'T   '
    AND SystemEntitySettings.IsSystemPrivate = 0
```

Given the above T-SQL if I ran something like `WHERE EntityTypeiD <> 'T'` it would ignore the first query entirely but do something with the second (never returning any actual rows).

The issue I'm having, or rather, my question is, why is it that it cannot eliminate the query entirely from the view, when it does so in the CTE case?

## EDIT

I've observed some interesting things so far, I'm not ruling out the deal with parameterization but I can also achive the desiered effect by either specifying a query hint (apparently any will do) or rewrite the second join as a IN predicate since it is only a filter.

```
INNER JOIN SystemEntitySettings ON SystemEntitySettings.SystemID = s.SystemID
    AND SystemEntitySettings.EntityTypeID = 'T   '
    AND SystemEntitySettings.IsSystemPrivate = 0
```

...becomes...

```
 WHERE s.SystemID IN (
      SELECT SystemID 
      FROM dbo.SystemEntitySettings 
      WHERE EntityTypeID = 'T   ' AND IsSystemPrivate = 0
 )
```

But, the following query has the same issue. It appears as if it's related to the JOIN operations some how. (NOTE the additional JOIN with [Group] taking place in this query)

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(4), 'CF  ') EntityTypeID, s.SystemID, [dbo].[CareerForum].GroupID EntityID
FROM [dbo].[CareerForum] 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Group] ON [dbo].[Group].GroupID = [dbo].[CareerForum].GroupID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[System] s ON s.MasterSystemID = [dbo].[Group].SystemID
WHERE s.SystemID IN (SELECT SystemID FROM dbo.SystemEntitySettings WHERE EntityTypeID = 'CF  ' AND IsSystemPrivate = 0)
```

## Reproducible

The following script can be used to reproduce the issue. Notice how the execution plan is completely different wheter the query is run with a query hint or if the view is run using a cte (the desiered result).

```
CREATE DATABASE test_jan_20

USE test_jan_20

create table source (
    x int not null primary key,
)

insert into source values (1)
insert into source values (2)
insert into source values (3)
insert into source values (4)
insert into source values (5)
insert into source values (6)

create table other (
    y int not null primary key,
)

insert into other values (1)
insert into other values (2)
insert into other values (3)
insert into other values (4)
insert into other values (5)
insert into other values (6)

create view dummy AS (

    SELECT 'A' id, x, NULL y 
    FROM SOURCE 
    WHERE x BETWEEN 1 AND 2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'B' id, x, NULL y
    FROM SOURCE 
    WHERE x BETWEEN 3 AND 4

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'B' id, source.x, y
    FROM SOURCE 
    INNER JOIN other ON y = source.x
    INNER JOIN source s2 ON s2.x = y - 1 --i need this join for the issue to occur in the execution plan
    WHERE source.x BETWEEN 5 AND 6

)
GO

--this one fails to remove the JOIN, not OK
SELECT * FROM dummy WHERE id = 'c' 

--this is OK
SELECT * FROM dummy WHERE id = 'c' OPTION (HASH JOIN) --NOTE: any query hint seems to do the trick

--this is OK
;
WITH a AS (

    SELECT 'A' id, x, NULL y 
    FROM SOURCE 
    WHERE x BETWEEN 1 AND 2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'B' id, x, NULL y
    FROM SOURCE 
    WHERE x BETWEEN 3 AND 4

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'B' id, source.x, y
    FROM SOURCE 
    INNER JOIN other ON y = source.x
    INNER JOIN source s2 ON s2.x = y - 1 --i need this join for the issue to occur in the execution plan
    WHERE source.x BETWEEN 5 AND 6

)
SELECT * FROM a WHERE id = 'c'
```

Comment: Are you using string literals in both cases or are you using parameters? If string literals for both do you have forced parameterisation switched on on your server?

Comment: are both branches in the union query supposed to select 'T'?

Comment: @Martin - literals no forced parameterization. @cyberkiwi - this is but a small portion of the entire query, there many other queryies that are all concatenated using UNION ALL, these two are both supposed to select 'T'

Comment: OT really, but have you got a weird license for SQL Server where you have to pay for each view you create? I don't understand why you'd want to stuff all of these different queries into a single view.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - We have general purpose tables that store generic information, these relations are identified by storing an type and id. It's a way of implementing a global id. Then there's plenty of dynamic aspects surrounding these global ids, I can't be sure to know what view to use in what scenario. However, I always know what the `EntityTypeID` is and we use this for several meta models. It just works better for us, this way.

Comment: Well it's obviously to do with auto parameterisation. The version without the query hint gets auto parameterised. Adding the query hint stops this from happening. Not sure why this makes any difference in this case but doesn't in the test script in my answer though. Maybe something to do with the optimization level these are trivial plans

Comment: Also note that because 0 rows come out of the constant scan the inner side of the nested loops join never actually gets executed so maybe the query optimiser just realises that plan is cheap enough and stops evaluating plans at that stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The execution plan is showing that the
>   queries that doesn't match on ID never
>   run.

That is correct since you provided a constant 'A', so the plan is built against the specific string 'A', which cuts off one part.

> The issue I'm having, or rather, my
>   question is, why is it that it cannot
>   eliminate the query entirely from the
>   view, when it does so in the CTE case?

I thought you just stated that it did?  I guess you are using it in a parameterized way, either in an SP, function or parameterized query.  This causes a plan to be created that MUST be able to take various parameters - so cutting one part out is out of the question.

To achieve what you want, you would have to generate dynamic SQL that would present the query with a `constant` value to the query optimizer.  This is true whether you use View or inline Table-valued function.

EDIT: **following addition of reproducible**

These two forms seem to work as well

```
select * from (SELECT * FROM dummy) y WHERE id = 'c' 

with a as (Select * from dummy) SELECT * FROM a WHERE id = 'c'
```

Comment: This makse sense. I've however observed that using a query hint (MERGE|HASH|LOOP) join actually makes the result more like I want, or by restating the JOIN using a IN predicate. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: That's it! I actually moved the answer, becuase this is what solved the problem for me. I had to rewrite my inner joins using nested subqueries and subquery expression for the result to come back as I wanted it to. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

In your test case this is what is happening.

For the query with the view and the query hint or the CTE the Query Optimiser is using "contradiction detection". You can see in the execution plan properties that the `OPTIMIZATION LEVEL` is `TRIVIAL`. The trivial plan churned out is exactly the same as the one shown in point 8 of [this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/13-things-you-should-know-about-statistics-and-the-query-optimizer/).

For the query with the view without the query hint this gets auto parameterised. This can prevent the contradiction detection from kicking in [as covered here](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/conor/post/Contradictions-within-Contradictions.aspx).

Comment: I believe you need to add a JOIN for this to problem to occur, I've updated my answer a bit. I'll see if I can't provide a reproducible test case as well.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in isolation. I've expanded the question a bit though.

Comment: I've managed to reproduce the issue, please take a look @Matrin and tell me if you know why this is happening. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

With you last update, the query is optimized too.

If you provide `c` (or any pother missing value) as a filter, you will have this plan:

```
  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Union1019]=[Expr1018], [Union1020]=[ee].[dbo].[source].[x], [Union1021]=[ee].[dbo].[other].[y]))
       |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1018]='B'))
            |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Expr1022]))
                 |--Constant Scan
                 |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([ee].[dbo].[source].[PK__source__3BD019E5171A1207] AS [s2]), SEEK:([s2].[x]=[Expr1022]) ORDERED FORWARD)
```

, with the constant scan expanding as follows:

```
<RelOp AvgRowSize="19" EstimateCPU="1.57E-07" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="0" LogicalOp="Constant Scan" NodeId="3" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Constant Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="1.57E-07">
  <OutputList>
    <ColumnReference Database="[ee]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[source]" Column="x" />
    <ColumnReference Database="[ee]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[other]" Column="y" />
    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1022" />
  </OutputList>
  <ConstantScan />
</RelOp>
```

In other worlds, `source s` and `other o` are never touched, this does not produce any real output, and, hence, there is no input for the `Nested Loops`, so no actual seeks are performed.

If you substitute the parameter with `b`, you will see a more complex plan with actual `JOIN` operations against all three tables.

Comment: How does this explain that the evaluation is different when the using a CTE with regards to the view in my example? This is all very interesting but I don't understand how it can be different, or rather, what I need to do to make sure that it works the way I want it to.